# Magento 2 How to generate dynamic CSS?

Tags: magento2, less-css

Is that possible to generate dynamic less CSS?

Is there any other way without replacing dynamic CSS in phtml file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible to generate dynamic less file. We can change the content of less file to. No need to place CSS in phtml file.

Comment: Can you elaborate how to do this?